# DRY up React code. Multiple button components that change the parent component's background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, components, dry

I'm sure there is a way to DRY the code. All changeColor() is doing is changing the background color of the parent component .

```
import { Play } from "./play";
import { Hello } from "./hello";
import { styles } from "./styles";`

export class Buttons extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: styles.container
        };
        this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
        this.changeColor1 = this.changeColor1.bind(this);
        this.changeColor2 = this.changeColor2.bind(this);
    }
    changeColor(newColor) {
        this.setState({
            color: styles.backPlay
        });
    }
    changeColor1(newColor) {
        this.setState({
            color: styles.backTime
        });
    }
    changeColor2(newColor) {
        this.setState({
            color: styles.backHello
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.state.color}>
                <Play onClick={this.changeColor} />
                <Time onClick={this.changeColor1} />
                <Hello onClick={this.changeColor2} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the styles page, which I also think can use a little DRY. Container, backPlay, backTime and backHello all represent the same container but a different background.

**styles.js**

```
export var styles = {
    loc: {
        padding: 25,
        margin: 40,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    green: {
        color: "green",
        background: "#59D13E"
    },
    red: {
        color: "yellow",
        background: "#A9A81D"
    },
    blue: {
        color: "blue",
        background: "#34BEE3"
    },
    container: {
        display: "inline-block",
        textAlign: "center",
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 40

    },
    backPlay: {
        display: "inline-block",
        textAlign: "center",
        background: "yellow",
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 40
    },
    backTime: {
        display: "inline-block",
        textAlign: "center",
        background: "blue",
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 40
    },
    backHello: {
        display: "inline-block",
        textAlign: "center",
        background: "green",
        marginTop: 50,
        padding: 40
    },
    mainCont: {
        height: "100vh",
        textAlign: "center",
        background: "#FFA692"
    }
};
```

---

### **UPDATE**

I found a better way to DRY up this code. By using one button component and manipulating it's state. Let me know if there is even a better way to do this.

**ButtonContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from './Button'

export default class ButtonContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
    }
    toggleClass = (color, id) => {
        let colors = [...this.state.colors]
        const newColors = colors.map((newColor, index) => {
            if (id === index) {
                const copyMap = { 0: 'red', 1: 'blue', 2: 'green' }
                const copy = color === 'not' ? copyMap[index] : 'not'
                return copy
            } else {
                return newColor
            }
        })
        this.setState({ colors: newColors })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='button-container'>
                {this.state.colors.map((color, index) =>
                    <Button
                        toggleClass={this.toggleClass}
                        key={index}
                        id={index}
                        name={color}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Button = (props) => (
    <button
        className={`button-component ${props.name}`}
        onClick={() => props.toggleClass(props.name, props.id)}
    >
        {props.name}
    </button>
)

export default Button
```

**_button-container.scss**

```
.button-container {
    margin: 10rem auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**_button.scss**

```
.button-component {
    padding: 4rem;
    margin: 0 2rem;
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.blue {
    background: blue;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}

.not {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.bind()` to pre-bind arguments to a function before passing it down as a prop:

```
export class Buttons extends React.Component {
    state = {
        color: styles.container
    };
    changeColor = newColor => {
        this.setState({
            color: newColor
        });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.state.color}>
                <Play onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, styles.backPlay)} />
                <Time onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, styles.backTime)} />
                <Hello onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, styles.backHello)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can also remove your constructor and use fat arrow functions to autobind your methods to the component.

**styles.js**

```
const container = {
    display: "inline-block",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 40
};

export const styles = {
    loc: {
        padding: 25,
        margin: 40,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    green: {
        color: "green",
        background: "#59D13E"
    },
    red: {
        color: "yellow",
        background: "#A9A81D"
    },
    blue: {
        color: "blue",
        background: "#34BEE3"
    },
    container,
    backPlay: {
        ...container,
        background: "yellow"
    },
    backTime: {
        ...container,
        background: "blue"
    },
    backHello: {
        ...container,
        background: "green"
    },
    mainCont: {
        height: "100vh",
        textAlign: "center",
        background: "#FFA692"
    }
};
```

You can use the [es6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to copy the contents of `styles.container` to each style, and then override the `color` property.

Comment: Every time render gets called you are creating new event handlers via `.bind()`. These handlers should be lifted into class methods and passed as a reference instead, otherwise you break pure components downstream.

Comment: I tried using the es6 spread operator and it said it couldn't read the property 'container'. Do I have to install a package or something to make it work?

Comment: @DannyDelott Thanks for the downvote. Your suggestion doesn't work for OPs case. You described what he had, but didn't want. This demonstrates a more DRY way of writing this component. If OP was concerned about optimal performance, then this would have been a different question.

Comment: @DerfMongrel You may need to pull `container` out into a separate object and then merge it into styles and each rule. Updated answer showing how to do that.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Thanks a lot, I had to change 'container: ' to 'container =' and that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your color changing functions are very similar, you can pass in the name of the style you want to apply and use it inside the function, thus saving you the repetition.

```
changeColor(attr) {
    this.setState({
        color: styles[attr]
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={this.state.color}>
            <Play onClick={() => this.changeColor('backPlay')} />
            <Time onClick={() => this.changeColor('backTime')} />
            <Hello onClick={() => this.changeColor('backHello')} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't declare event handlers inline in the render method as this breaks pure components downstream. These should be lifted into class methods and passed as a reference.